# architecture for searching large scale user activity logs with sub second performance

Tags: architecture

We have two different requirements:-

1. A system that logs 21 different kinds of events triggered by the user and searches them within 7 years worth of data (approx 4TB) with sub-second performance.
2. A system that logs 3500 different kinds of events by user and searches them within 2 years worth of data (again approx 4TB) but performance can be more than a second.

We thought to use a Kafka listener to listen two these events and publish them to two different data sources(currently we are using SQL DB) based on the two different requirements.

However, we are trying to search for a possibility if we can use some technology to do this with a single data source as the 21 events is a subset of the 3500 events.

Joining the two requirements together it becomes:-

A system that logs 3500 different kinds of user events triggered by the user and searches them within 7 years worth of data (15TB approx) within the sub-second performance.

Sample row in the table:-

```
+------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------------+
| Account No | Time Created | Action/Event  |       Action Data        |
+------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------------+
|   12345678 |   1527605672 | Account Login | User logged into account |
+------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------------+
```

The query that requires a sub-second performance is:-

select * from table where Account No = 12345678 AND DATE BETWEEN 'x' and 'y'. x and y will be any range within last two years.

Comment: Is your SQL DB able to query that much data in under a second?

Comment: Can use Elasticsearch Hadoop instead of SQL DB

Comment: @cricket_007 We are open to move the data to a different db as well.

Comment: Elasticsearch or Solr work well for the query you gave... But I'm assuming you'd want some more flexibility?

Comment: @cricket_007 Will vanilla elasticsearch be enough to search in 15TB data with sub-second performance?

Comment: I don't have much experience with either. But both of those store indices and simply work really well for date ranges and field matching. There's also a Kafka Connect elasticsearch plugin